# How to lock an instance when a method is being executed

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I don't know if this question is redundant or not but I could find the answer after looking for 2 hours...

I'm trying to make a program that uses multiple threads and a shared instance of a class. When a certain method on this instance is being called, let's call it "reconnect", other method calls should wait until "reconnect" is finished executing. How do I achieve this?

Is it just:

```
synchronized (this) { //////// }
```

or:

```
public ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void reconnect() {

    lock.lock();

    ////

    lock.unlock();

}
```

Sorry if this was already asked. Thanks for reading.

Addition 1:

This was mentioned in the comments, when a method, other than "reconnect" is being executed, and "reconnect" is called, "reconnect" should wait until every other method is done executing.

Comment: Its called different things in different languages, but you want to lock the instance of the class.  This essentially allows one thread to say "its mine" until it lets it go.  There are a lot of things that you should read up on with regards to threads if you aren't used to using them (race conditions for example and dead lock)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html

Comment: I found that example hard to understand which is why I ignored it and looked further.

Comment: In a greatly generalized sense, you can lock and unlock the way you have mentioned and make something thread safe.  This is taking a lot of complex things and making them super simple, however.

Comment: The `synchronized` block is a lock, yes, but it may not be correct for your situation. You can guarantee correctness by having a `synchronized` block around *every method* in your class, but this means methods other than `reconnect()` cannot execute in parallel. You need to clarify your situation here: if you call `reconnect()` while another method is executing, do you want `reconnect()` to wait until all other methods are done?

Comment: @univerio Yes, if another method is being executed when reconnect is issued, reconnect should wait until that other method is finished executing. Placing everything in synchronized blocks defeats the purpose of using multi threading, doesn't it?

Comment: Exactly. In that case, you can use [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). Acquire the write lock in your `reconnect()` method and acquire the read lock in all other methods. This will guarantee no other method can execute while `reconnect()` is executing, while all other methods can still execute in parallel.

Comment: @univerio Thanks a lot! I couldn't find this anywhere. I'm testing now. Will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the complexity of your program. The first is adequate for very basic tasks. The latter(Lock objects) is part of the high level concurrency objects suitable for more advanced tasks. The biggest advantage of Lock objects over implicit locks is their ability to back out of an attempt to acquire a lock.

Comment: So if I synchronize this, other method calls will hold until the synchronisation is stopped?

Comment: It is a very basic program btw. I have a connection model which is updated by reconnect and used by all the other methods.

Comment: @MartijnRiemers In both cases only one thread can use the method, in the first case if one thread has a lock on the method subsequent threads calling the same method will get "locked" till the first thread is done with method. In the second case though a thread can attempt to get a lock on the method and if it sees that another thread is already holding it, it can back out(and do other tasks) and try again later

Comment: @MartijnRiemers, Just to be clear, Locking in Java is cooperative:  Synchronizing on an object does NOT prevent other threads from changing the state of the object.  All it does is prevent other threads from synchronizing on the same object at the same time.  If you want to prevent other threads from modifying the object, then _every method_ that can change the object must be "synchronized".

Answer (score 0):

Only the first option (or the equvivalent `synchronized` method modifier) was available until Java version 5.0. The second option is available in 5.0 and later versions.

The two are equivalent, if used correctly (your second example should be extended with a try-finally block)

The drawback of the first method is that you have only one condition variable at your disposal, otherwise it is more convenient (and less error-prone) to use.

You have to use the second form if you want more than one condition variable.